# How to display a dataset in a table format in tkinter gui app

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to display the contents of a 2D list in a table format on a tkinter gui I am making. From what I understand tkinter doesn't have a built in method for creating tables, is there a way I can mimic a table, or maybe display an externally generated HTML table? (Just to spitball an idea)

Comment: Look at `ttk.Treeview`. It can be configured to act like a table.

Comment: I will look into it, thank you.

Comment: That worked really well, does Treeview have any style options? I'd like to make the table as visually appealing as possible

Comment: Look at `ttk.Style`. You can use that to configure the style of any `ttk` widget. But I don't know how to use it... You might want to look at some tutorials.

Comment: As one of the possible options: https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable